# Manually install a windows application with no installer

Tags: windows-10, installation, chromium

I have recently downloaded chromium from [here](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/). However it seems that it only downloads the files required only to run chromium on the spot (Portable) but not to install it (no installer). So is there a way to install it as an application manually with only those files so it can be identified by windows and also able to set it as default browser.

Comment: Unclear: Why are you not downloading the installer? Why Chromium and not Chrome?

Comment: , I just want to know is there a way to install a program in this kind of situation, but first, do you have any Idea how to do it . . .

Comment: Of course there's a way - all one has to do is duplicate all the registry changes that are done by the installer. Unfortunately, Chrome/Chromium does not document them.

Comment: Thanks... but is there a source where we can learn all the registry tweaks to be done